# Using Firebase authentication with appengine decorator

Tags: firebase-authentication, google-app-engine-python

I'd like to use Firebase to authenticate/authorize the user in my web app, but then use the AppEngine decorator in Python to make API calls to the user's Google Contacts/Calendar from the backend if the user authenticates with a Google account. Is it possible to carry on the Firebase authentication/authorization to the appengine decorator?

Comment: You can probably verify and decode the token: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens

Comment: I can verify the token on the backend, but how can I use that token with the decorator to make a backend call to the APIs? I've been using @decorator.oauth_required and then decorator.http() to get an authorized http object. Can I use that token somehow to create the authorized http object instead of the decorator?

Comment: What Firebase feature are you trying to invoke from your app engine code?

Comment: I'd like to use Firebase authentication. If the user authenticates with Google I want to be able to make backend calls to the Google APIs. If he authenticates with FB or email I'll skip the Google API calls.

Comment: Ah, I get it now: it's the other way around: you want to call Google APIs based on the Firebase Authentication token. Sorry for being slow. In that case you're looking for the Access Token. A quick search only gives these relevant results: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40042077/how-do-i-get-the-current-users-access-token-in-angularfire2/40043964#40043964), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38004233/how-to-get-accesstoken-for-firebase-3-using-javascript), but both seem client-side only. I don't think any of the relevant OAuth token is transferred to the server in the JWT.

Comment: Right, I haven't been able to find that either, but was hoping it was possible. Thank you for looking into it!

Comment: It turns out that this actually works without sending any tokens from the client/Firebase to my backend. If I authenticate/authorize with Firebase I can make authorized Google API calls using the python decorator without having to re-authenticate.

Comment: Good to hear. Feel like providing a self-answer (preferably with some code that shows how you authenticate with Firebase and then call app engine)?